# Splash screen image for Blackberry, Blackberry webworks

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a phonegap application in Blackberry. I have a splash screen that is shown on launching the app thats fine. But for different dimensions, how can I make the splash screen fit to the device. Also how can I add a loading indicator on the splash screen? I am a web developer so I don't know how to change in java files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `.getScreenSize()` function which would get the size of the screen and then after getting the size of the screen, set the image size of the splash screen as per the coordinates got but the function. I hope this should solve your problem. Do some research on the function.